# Ungrouping an Excel/Powerpoint Bubble Chart from wmf/emf

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I'm looking to access the individual bubbles in a bubble chart.

[image]

When I save the chart as wmf/emf and then ungroup it the bubbles get hidden by squares. Is there a way to prevent the squares from appearing and a direct way of accessing just the bubbles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use the 'Vary colors by point' option to color the bubbles and save the chart as emf/wmf - that is when the squares/rectangles appear.

Instead if you choose to use the 'solid fill' option to color the bubbles, only the oval shapes appear.